# Finish, complete, submit, or finished at the end of a short drag and drop word bank quiz that isn't graded?

Tags: word-choice

What term's better for the finish or submit button at the end of a short, optional, test quiz?

The quiz is a drag and drop with a word bank, and the button I'm talking about will check their answers, and tell them if they're good to go, or might want to go back and review the material before continuing.

I thought of the following:

- Finish - A little informal, and I think there's a slight connotation of being required to do so and so, or considering it a chore when the word finished is used. These are optional.
- Finished - Past tense seems a little more awkward than future tense, and the same issue as above.
- Submit - The short quiz is not to be graded, rather it serves as one of many practice interactive pages to break up the monotomy of reading through a 70 page course and give the user a small recap of the last several pages. The word submit makes me think something is formally being handed it for grading or review. The button does serve to check the answers, give the use a score, and tell them whether they're ready to move on, or may want to consider reviewing the last section first.
- Complete - Similar issue to the word submit. It seems a little like this is important, is required, or might count towards the students grade in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not "Check Answers"? That is what the user is really doing.

Although, I think you've failed to include the most important information: Who is your target audience? Grade school kids, high school or college? English as a Second Language? What is their average reading level?

Also, you might consider the design of the page. Is there only one call to action, which is the form submission? If so, the language may not be as important as you think. Users will see the button, it will say submit/go/check/done/complete, and it will probably be located in the lower left or right corner, which is standard UI.

If you can't test your unique audience, make sure UI pattern is clear and you should still be fine. Also, while user's don't read, when it comes to a test a short instruction at the top of the form that tells them "this is not a graded test" should suffice to qualm any fears that the submit button means geting reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind labeling a button should always be `'What does clicking the button do?'`

`Finish/Finished and Complete/Completed` do not sound right. It sounds like when I click the button it will 'Finish'/'Complete' the quiz for me. **They sound better as status messages than as button labels.**

Submit is a good generic choice. `Submit Answers` is a good explanatory label and if you were to grade the answers then, `Submit for grading` is a good choice. **It implies that it will take your finished work and submit it to the system**, be it for grading, or some other purpose.

---

**TL;DR Use submit unless you have a better contextual verb.**

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Zak that it must be relevant to your audience; how about "Score me!"? 'score' is based around what your users want to get, rather than the mechanism of sending the information to the server (submit), or ending the test (finish/finished/complete).